# How does this javascript class and method work?

Tags: javascript, twilio

As seen [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection#example) from Twilio's documentation, how does the following code work? We have a `connection` class and an `on` method. If I haven't previously defined what `hasEarlyMedia`, `showRingingIndicator`, or `playOutgoingRinging` mean, then how does the `on` method know what they mean and what to do with them? Thanks.

```
connection.on('ringing', function(hasEarlyMedia) {
  showRingingIndicator();
  if (hasEarlyMedia) { playOutgoingRinging(); }
});
```

Comment: `showRingingIndicator` and `playOutgoingRinging` should be defined _somewhere_. `hasEarlyMedia` is an argument that gets passed by the callback mechanism of the `on` method.

Comment: The functions are presumably defined in the Twilio library that you loaded.

Comment: You might want to read the text before the example which explains all your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe is easier to understand if we rewrite the code like this:

---

```
// when the Connection has entered the ringing state,
// call handleRingingEvent (callback function) and pass an argument, 
// a boolean denoting whether there is early media available from the callee
connection.on('ringing', handleRingingEvent);

function handleRingingEvent(hasEarlyMedia) {

    showRingingIndicator();

    if (hasEarlyMedia) {
        playOutgoingRinging();
    }

}

// if not defined somewhere else 
function showRingingIndicator() {
    // do something
}

// if not defined somewhere else     
function playOutgoingRinging() {
    // do something
}
```

---

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`hasEarlyMedia` is an argument. Please [check](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)

`showRingingIndicator();` and `playOutgoingRinging();` method must be defined somewhere. Must be function declared in your one of the library which you have included in your file.